# Why can't I use trigonometric functions here?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

[image]

I tried solving this answer by using trig functions to get the answer (E). First I calculated angle FBC which was 30 and then i used sin 30 to get the length of FC. then I got the length of line BF (Using Pythagoras) and I used the formula of the area of a triangle to get (E) but when I checked the memo, it says the correct answer was (C). Why is this? What did I do wrong? Shouldn't it be (E)?

Comment: Can you be more specific?  How did you use trig functions to arrive at your answer?

Comment: Just edited it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Drop a perpendicular from $F$ to $\overline{AB}$ at $M$ and a perpendicular from $F$ to $\overline{BC}$ at $N$. Then $|FN|=|MB|$ is the shorter leg of a $30$-$60$-$90$ right triangle, and $|FM|=|NB|$ is the longer leg, so $|FM|=\sqrt3|FN|$. $\triangle FBC$ and $\triangle FBA$ have bases $|BC|=|BA|$ and altitudes $|FN|$ and $|FM|$, so if $a$ is the area of $\triangle FBC$, then the area of $\triangle FBA$ is $a\sqrt3$. The area of the square is $4$, so $a+a\sqrt3=2$, and

$$a=\frac2{1+\sqrt3}=\sqrt3-1\;.$$

Comment: Thank you, but may I ask how did you get FM = square root of 3? and what does the 2 lines between FN (|   |) mean? Absolute value?

Comment: @user108104: You’re welcome. $\overline{FM}$ is the line segment from $F$ to $M$; $|FM|$ is the length of that line segment. I didn’t say that $|FM|$ was $\sqrt3$: it’s $\sqrt3|FN|$, i.e., $\sqrt3$ times the length of the segment $\overline{FN}$. That’s a basic fact about $30$-$60$-$90$ right triangles: the longer leg is $\sqrt3$ times the shorter leg (and the hypotenuse is twice the shorter leg).

Comment: Oh, because this question was from an Olympiad. I never expected teens like me to know that rule.

Answer (score 2):

You used $\sin(30) = FC/FB$ but to use that, the angle of $BFC$ would need to be 90 degrees, but alas, it is not.

Comment: How do you know its not 90 degrees?

Comment: Angle $BAF$ is $45^\circ$, so $AFB$ is $75^\circ$, so $BFC$ is $105^\circ$.  But the burden of proof is on you to know $BFC$ is $90^\circ$ to do this trig solution, not the other way around.

Comment: Since we have a square, and AC is the diagonal, BAF must be 45. Since FBA=60, it must be that $AFB = 180-60-45 = 75$. Since BFC is it's compliment, $BFC=180-AFB=105$.